# How to Scroll my image left to right using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

> I want to scroll an image from left to right and right to left. This
>   means when the image did finish scroll left to right then
>   automatically right to left scrolling is enabled and then repeats it.
>   I want only show 4 images first and rest are scroll

**here is my code:-**

```
export default class Gallery extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <a >&#10094;</a>
        <div >
          <div >1</div>
          <div >2</div>
          <div >3</div>
          <div >4</div>
          <div >5</div>
          <div >6</div>
          <div >7</div>
          <div >8</div>
          <div >9</div>
          <div >10</div>
        </div>
        <a >&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

here is the image :-
[image: i want only 4 box is showing and rest are scrolling]

Answer (score 0):

if you want proper solution which has common behaviour throughout browsers as well as 'while scrolling, there should be transition', 'autoplay' etc etc,
then you should use react-slick which enables many options out of the box

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick

also see example which fits your use-case

https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/multiple-items

Comment: set 
```
slidesToScroll : 1
```
if you want to change 1 image at a time